# Values in Sharedpreferences are only available after app is restarted

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-appwidget

I'm using an App Widget Configuration Activity for setting up some settings for my widget. When the user confirms, settings are saved to **Sharedpreferences** by calling **saveWidgetConfig(Config)**. Later when the Broadcast for refreshing the widgets is received (first Alarm is after 1000ms) the configuration is loaded again by calling **loadWidgetConfig(id)**. See simple implementation below.

The Problem now is that even though I

- call editor.apply() (or commit() - doesn't change anything)
- don't use static classes => every time I create an object:
  new WidgetConfiguration(context)

when trying to access the SharedPreferences from my receiver class, it doesn't contain any preference for the given key.

**BUT**:

- if I try to access the preference directly after apply/commit, it works - even if I create a new WidgetConfiguration class
- it also works after I restart the device or run a new version from ecipse

So I think it has something to be with different contexts or that I get different "versions" of the Sharedpreferences. But up to now (more than three hours!!!) I was't able to figure out... :-(

```
public class WidgetConfiguration {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String LOG_TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    public WidgetConfiguration(Context context) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public static String KEY_WIDGET_CONFIG = "single_widget_object_config_";

    public void saveWidgetConfig(Widget widget) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(widget);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_WIDGET_CONFIG + widget.getAppwidgetID(), json);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "saved widget id " + widget.getAppwidgetID() + "\n" + json);
        editor.apply();
    };

    public Widget loadWidgetConfig(int appwidgetID) {
        Widget loadedWidget = null;
        String key = KEY_WIDGET_CONFIG + appwidgetID;
        if (prefs.contains(key))
        {
            String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "loaded widget id " + appwidgetID + "\n" + json);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            loadedWidget = gson.fromJson(json, Widget.class);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "no preferences found for widget: " + key);
        }

        return loadedWidget;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you save it with 
"saved widget id " + KEY_WIDGET_CONFIG + widget.getAppwidgetID()

and you try to get it with a different key
KEY_WIDGET_CONFIG + appwidgetID

use the same key to get it

Comment: Oh yes, that was a copy&paste mistake when editing the log messages but this is not source of this issue.
As I said in the beginning, after a the app was completely shut down -it works - so it's not an issue of different keys.

Comment: instead of prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); try to use sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("someString", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); and when putting them sharedPreferences.edit()
      .putString("someString.key", json). This is from my own working code

Answer (score 1):

Put:

```
editor.commit();
```

instead of:

```
editor.apply();
```